# Else statement works even when If is told to return

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I'm not quite sure why, but I am unable to get this script to behave itself. I have an if statement followed by an else statement, nested within another if statement with its own else statement, and because the way the script is, the else statement is triggering, no matter what I do. I've tried exiting the function but it doesn't work. I have below, two versions of the script, one version using a switch statement, and one version using just if/else statements. They are in a string of identical functions.

What I want, is, if cost + memorybar.Value is greater than 100, it tells the user that, and turns the toggle back off, then exits the function. What is happening is, it turns the toggle off, then runs the else statement anyway, even when in the switch statement. Now the toggle works in reverse somehow. I've seen similar issues but even the return statement has been unable to solve this problem.

```
cost = 50;
    switch (power5.isOn) {
    case true:
        if (cost + memorybar.value > 100) {
            error.text = "Exeeds maximum memory";
            power5.isOn = false;
            break;
        } else {
            memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
            break;
        }
    case false:
        memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
        break;
    }



    if (power5.isOn == true) {
        if (cost + memorybar.value > 100) {
            error.text = "Exeeds maximum memory";
            power5.isOn = false;
            return;
        } else
            memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
        return;
    }
    else
        memorybar.value = memorybar.value - cost;
```

Comment: A `switch` on a boolean value is a bit overkill. Save yourself the trouble and convert it to an `if(power5.isOn) { }  else { }` statement. Also, I don't know what kind of effect it has when you modify the variable inside the `switch` inside the code of the switch-statement.

Comment: The first thing I would do if I were you, would be placing braces for `if-else` even if it contains one statement.

Comment: Not sure if unity is doing any optimization or changes on the fly that you might not see... but your code does what you want it to do. I think (like @GrantWinney) something else is causing your perceived symptom.

Comment: Maybe this will help clarify the issue. I will give an example of what is happening. As I said, this is just one in a variety of identical scripts, with the only difference being the value of "cost". So, I run the program and press the others until memorybar.value = 51. I click the toggle for this script, and .value becomes 1.

Answer (score 1):

No need of return statement, Use this code.

```
if (power5.isOn)
{
     if (cost + memorybar.value > 100)
     {
           error.text = "Exeeds maximum memory";
           power5.isOn = false;
     }
     else
     {
           memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
     }
}
else
{
      memorybar.value = memorybar.value - cost;
}
```

Comment: Note that `if (power5.isOn == true)` is superfluous. Whether a boolean expression evaluates to true is the same thing as just evaluating the expression. You can just say `if (power5.isOn)`. What you did isn't wrong, but it is more wordy.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I agree with you, Removed unnecessary code.

Comment: @MechaScoots   Is there some sort of eventhandler (for instance like NotifyPropertyChanged) which executes your script on an update of the `isOn` property? So, it's not running the `false` case after the `true` case, but it executes in a new call of the script. Try setting a breakpoint at the beginning of your script and check if it is called twice. Or set a breakpoint in each of the cases and check the stacktrace, if it's really the same call.

Comment: I did do a check for that, and somehow the false script is being called 1st, then the true script.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch triggers on `power5.isOn`, and setting it to false will cause the second switch case to also evaluate to true. Implement this using a standard if statement and it will work.

```
cost = 50;
if (power5.isOn)
{
    if (cost + memorybar.value > 100)
    {
        error.text = "Exeeds maximum memory";
        power5.isOn = false;  
    }
    else
    {
        memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;

    }
}
else
{
    memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `switch` works that way in c#. If one case is selected, it does not fall into another case even if you change the variable you switch on. See the following fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/0xuahj. Following your theory, it should print "1" and "2", but it only prints "1"

Answer (score 0):

For the first example

```
switch (power5.isOn) {
case true:
    if (cost + memorybar.value > 100) {
        error.text = "Exeeds maximum memory";
        power5.isOn = false;
        break;
    } else {
        memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
        break;
    }
case false:
    memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
    break;
}
```

I have tried and failed to reproduce your issue as follows:

```
bool powered = true;
int cost = 50;
int memorybar = 96;
switch (powered)
{
    case true:
        if (cost + memorybar > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("entered A");
            powered = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("entered B");
            memorybar = memorybar + cost;
            break;
        }
    case false:
        Console.WriteLine("entered C");
        memorybar = memorybar + cost;
        break;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This prints "entered A" and nothing else.

Unless you can create a self contained example it seems more likely that you've confused yourself with the rest of the logic in your program. Is it possible that you are actually invoking this code twice and that is your problem? Make sure that that isn't the case by making putting in a Debug.Log message before you even enter the switch and seeing if it is printed twice.

I can't help much more than that without a reproducible example.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and it's calling A and C. Actually, it's calling C then A.

Answer (score 0):

By what you described, it seems you are running this code inside Update() or another continous call,  what is happening is that once power is turned off, the code is still being called ad each cycle.

What you should do is have another flag stating whether this code should be called or not.

e.g.

```
OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.Tag == "powerTrigger") {
       updatePower = true;
    }
}

Update(){
    if(updatePower){
        if (power5.isOn){
            if (cost + memorybar.value > 100){
                error.text = "Exeeds maximum memory";
                power5.isOn = false;
            } else{
                memorybar.value = memorybar.value + cost;
            }
        } else{
            memorybar.value = memorybar.value - cost;
            if(memorybar.cost <= 0){
                memomrybar.cost = 0;
                updatePower = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not, I have a toggle and when the toggle is clicked, this script runs. It is an isolated function.

Comment: Could you tell which event are you using to call it ? If it is OnMouseDown() try on MouseUp() instead.

Comment: Neither, it's a canvas object that triggers it. It's 'OnValueChanged'